# Ef Code first One to one relationship with id as foreign

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I'm traying to do a mapping with  One to One relationship with id as "foreign", I can't change the database

Those are the tables

**Cutomer**

- int CustomerId
- string Name

**CustomerDetail**

- int CustomerId
- string Details

Entity Splittitng does not works for me since i need a left outter join.
Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance, 
and sorry about my english.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Shared Primary Key mapping here.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual CustomerDetail CustomerDetail { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerDetail
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string Details { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerDetail>().HasKey(d => d.CustomerId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasOptional(c => c.CustomerDetail)
            .WithRequired(d => d.Customer);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alfredo you can't expect EF to produce the most efficient queries. However query optimizer maybe able to optimize it. You can accept the answer if it is helpful to you.